# How to solve Capacitor iOS app error with connection to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiftui, capacitor

I faced this problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq3P8.png)
starting capacitor project with configuration file looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifeN6.png)

I think the problem is that iOS app doesn't allow us to connect to http site (only secured https). I found solution to write this to Info Xcode project file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlLxy.png)
but the connection is still unable to make.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.